# Autocovariance of wide-sense stationary ergodic process

Tags: estimation, covariance

Will the next covariance lag-l function unbiased estimation properly true for wide-sense stationary process?
$$E[(X_t - \mu)(X_{t-l} - \mu)] = {{1}\over{T-l-1}} (\sum_{i=l}^{T}{X_i X_{i-l}} - \mu^2)$$
Or preferable will be
$${{1}\over{T-l-1}} \sum_{i=l}^{T}{(X_i - \mu)(X_{i-l} - \mu)}.$$
Is there exist common used fast method of covariance estimation for such kind of processes, where sample is given? Thanks.